# Updating the values on Many-to-Many relationship table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing an issue on the many to many relationship table using ruby on rails.

I have two tables and a relationship table(which is a joining table). They are named as follow

1. User
2. Role
3. Role_User

My problem is how do i update the values of user roles on the 3rd table.

### Example

If I assign a

user_id 34 to admin(role_id = 2)

user_id 34 to supervisor(role_id = 3)

I should have two entries on Role_User table. Now I would like to update user_id 34 to admin(role_id = 1) How do I do this on rails

I have updating the user details with `update_all` command on rails like below

```
@user = User.where(id: user_params[:id]);
@user.update_all(
    first_name: user_params[:first_name],
    last_name: user_params[:last_name],
    email: user_params[:email],
    contact_number: user_params[:contact_number],
    user_name: user_params[:user_name],
    password: user_params[:password]
);
```

I try to update the role of users using the following code but it fails

```
@roles = user_params[:roles];
for role in @roles
  @user.roles << Role.find(role)
end

@user.save;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like that:

```
role = Role.find(ID)
user.roles << role
user.save
```

Comment: So first Do I need to remove the existing records in the third table ?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `has_many :through`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I'm using has_belong_to_many. Insertion is happening fine. Could you please check my question again. How do I do this in the code level

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a many_to_many connection through rails, like below for example, then you don't have to touch the relational table. As nifCody said, you simply have to tell rails that you're appending to the user's roles and (as long as you have the proper associations) rails will automatically update the middle table for you.

`class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end`

`class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end`

`class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end`

But essentially, whatever is in the table is what rails sees. So if you already have data in the tables, you can leave it and continue with the method nifCody suggested. It is simply a different way of **modifying** the data not **accessing** it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to doing the updates on the third relationship table as following code,

1. First I delete all role_id for the particular user_id
2. Then insert the roles as new to the particular user_id

Here is the code I have written

```
@user = User.find(user_params[:id])
@roles = @user.roles.all

@roles = @user.roles.all
for role in @roles
  if role
    @user.roles.delete(role)
  end
end

@user = User.find(user_params[:id])
@roles = user_params[:roles];
for role in @roles
  @user.roles << Role.find(role)
end

if @roles
  @user.save
end
```

Comment: Do we have any other efficient way to do this?